# Macro to format a specific set of cells in a column from 'General' to 'Number'

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel spreadsheet with multiple columns of data that have been exported from another application.  In Column C all data is formatted as 'General' by default.  The columns contains data in the following format examples:
example 1: 123.4560
example 2: 12345 (these can range from 5 to 8 numbers in length)
example 3: VTPH50000UG.  to
I need to format all cells in example 2 to 'Number' format but ignore all cells that contain data in examples 1 and 3.   I am new to Macros/VB and have searched extensively but just cannot find what I need.  Any help appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

This code is untested, but I would try something like this:

```
Sub Test()
Dim EndRow as Long
workbooks("Workbookname").sheets("Sheet1").activate
EndRow=cells(rows.count,1).end(xlup).row

If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber ("C2:C" & EndRow)
Range("C2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).NumberFormat ="0.00"
Else
End if
End sub
```